# Get form data from client to server side NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, postman

I would like send send file from postman to the server, and then send this file to sharepoint using REST API.

When I send my file form-data format body from postman to the server I don't know how to recover it

When I do console.log(file) on server side I have nothing

Comment: You can use this middleware package to handle file uploads. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code of the nodeJS server? Without your used code part it is hard to give an answer but you can simply catch the post request as below.

You should use body-parser to receive your data.

run npm install body-parser

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.file)
}

app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Running on port: "+5000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working using multer

const multer  = require('multer')